# echo POST array.. or other ideas?

Tags: php, post, arrays, scripting

**Update:**

As seen in the Original Questions below, I am looking to echo an array.
The problem is that when I send the Moneris gateway to return a POST array to my new file (cart.php) it gets a 500 Internal Server Error.

This is the same error I received when it send to the script, which should have worked.
Is there any reason that it would always send a 500 Internal Server Error?

[Cart.php Direct Link](http://www.fastpixs.com/cgi-bin/cart.php)

Craig

---

ORIGINAL QUESTION:

Hello there,

I am back for another question.

Here is my dilemma:

I have a script (ImageFolio Commerce) that hasn't been updated on our server since.. probably 2003. The script had a Payment Gateway (Moneris) manually added to it by the company who offers the script. This costs $1000 to get them to add a gateway.

I now have a new client who purchased this business from the previous owner. While switching the account to the new owner's Moneris account, we found out that things have been updated.

**Long story short..**

The Moneris gateway can send 3 types of responses:

1. POST with XML Data
2. POST
3. GET

I imagine it is easiest to just use the POST array.
I have the file that it sends the response to. As of now the file responds with a Internal Server error, but it **does** process the order.

What I want to do is determine what the POST array is that is being sent, so that I can take it and echo it in a logical manner. Is there a way to capture and echo the entire POST?

Or can someone suggest a better method of doing this?

Thank you,

Craig

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of viewing the POSTed contents server side (as shown in Lizard's answer), you can *also* do so client-side...

The HTTP headers your client is sending can be viewed with tools such as **Firebug** for [Firefox](http://getfirebug.com/) and [Chrome](http://getfirebug.com/releases/lite/chrome/).

Comment: This sounds like it might work then. I have firebug, so I might just try looking into that.

Comment: Ok, so I can see exactly what is sent now (thanks for the easier method). However, I am still getting a 500 Internal Server Issue whenever I send data to the script from Moneris. Doesn't matter what I do, but it sends the transaction and then displays an error?

Comment: I think your 500 error is outside the scope of this question, but you should be able to access Apache/PHP's error logs on the server, which will give you more insight as to the cause of your 500 error.

Answer (score 2):

either

```
var_dump($_POST);
```

or

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($_POST);
echo "</pre>";
```

Both will output array in a readable format for you to analyse

Comment: Thank you very much. Trying this now. Ends up the files are all CGI and I completely missed that, so I'm going to send it through an external PHP file. (Don't know much about CGI at all)

Comment: I updated the question to a new question of sorts. It just doesn't work. Could it be that it's an https:// referencing an http:// page?